# how to draw a line or play sprites on the path of the player unity2d

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im trying to make a game were you move the the end and were you moved spikes appear that kill you. I cant figure out draw line in unity2d. Are therer any ways that I could do this

Comment: Your question is confusing. Why are you trying to draw a line? Are you trying to draw spikes manually as lines? Are you saying that the player is supposed to move towards the level end but if they touch spikes they die? Or are you just trying to figure out how to draw lines?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Main goal of the game: you platform to the end area which than spawns deadly things were you exactly walked and jumped. Now you have to make it back with the deadly stuff in the way. so. player walks here ------------ to the end. I then spawn objects were the line is. But I want jumping also to register. So _____------_____ end. Spawns objects along the lines.

Answer (score 1):

Use OnCollisionEnter or OnTriggerEnter on either the tiles or player to detect when the player has touched a tile. Add a list to the player that contains every tile that has been touched. At the end when you want to spawn spikes, go through the list of every touched tile and spawn spikes at their locations.